# Why is my Admob reward interstitial ad connected to Unity stuck on pending?

Tags: unity, advertisements, admob

I am trying to better monetize my game by using rewarded interstitials. I have set these up on my admob console. I have also linked the ad source on the admob console to my game through the Unity ads service using my game's id.

It seems to be stuck on "pending". I can't find any further options on admob or on the unity ads console to remedy this. In the game itself, my rewarded ads are not loading.

Is there some step I am missing either through Admob or Unity ads? How long does pending take because it has been like this for a few days.

**Edit with more info**
Unity version 5.5.1f1
I am using the example code from the admob site (I removed my apps id's here for privacy reasons):

```
    public RewardBasedVideoAd nonskipInterstich;
    public void NonSkipGoogleAd(){

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "--------------------------------------";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "------------------------------------------";
    #else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif


    nonskipInterstich = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    nonskipInterstich.LoadAd(request, adUnitId );  

    nonskipInterstich.OnAdFailedToLoad += LogFailedToLoadError;

}
```

if I display the failed to load event I get "No fill".
I haven't ever gotten it to fill a request, but I am only using remediation linked to the UnityAds source.

I read a post online that recommended importing the Unity Ads plugin from the asset store into the project. I did this and the google request is still not filling. I do not use the unity ads plugin directly to make the request. I also have the unity ads adapter jar found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There were a number of things I missed. After adding unity ads sdk and the adapter jar file for the unity network to my project in the GoogleMobileAds/libs folder I found that the "enable" button on the admob console activated the connection for the rewarded ads.

[image]